# Как вернуть значение из sessionStorage?

Tags: javascript

Помогите разобраться, есть следующий код

```
var a = new Map();
a.set("key1","value1")
a.set("key2","value2")
a.set("key3","value3")

sessionStorage.setItem("saveData", JSON.stringify(a));
var result = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("saveData"));
```

Как теперь обращаться к элементам `a` которые сохранены в сессии?
В JS не силен, поэтому прошу не сильно не кидаться

Comment: что значит как обращаться? А как пробуешь и что не получается?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский пробовал так `result.get("key1")` и `result.a.get("key1)`, может подскажете как прваильно?

Comment: `result.key1` видимо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Map` просто так в строку не перевести. Нужно чуть более хитрое действие. Вот так:

```
let mySerialMap = JSON.stringify(Array.from(myMap.entries()))
```

А обратно уже вот так:

```
let myMap = new Map(JSON.parse(mySerialMap))
```

В последнем примере вместо `mySerialMap` будет данные из хранилища

Comment: Попробовал, в итоге карта myMap пустая и при обращение к элементу ничего не вернулось

Comment: Скорее всего не так пишешь. Покажи полностью как применяешь то, что я описал

Comment: sessionStorage.setItem("mySave", JSON.stringify(Array.from(result)));
        var t = new Map(JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("mySave")))

        console.log(t.get("некий_элемент"))

Comment: кто такой result? как он выглядит?

Comment: result = new Map():
result.set("key1","value1")
result.set("key2, "value2")
и все в таком духе

Comment: А что в ответе написано? `result`  или всё же `result.entries()`?

Comment: let mySerialMap = JSON.stringify(Array.from(result.entries()))

        sessionStorage.setItem("bbb", mySerialMap);

        result = new Map(JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("bbb"));

        document.getElementById("date_end").value = result.get("date_end");

        console.log(result);

Comment: все равно пусто

Comment: пусто в консоли или пусто в value? ты добавил данный ключ в map? Показывай поооолный код... хоть на jsfiddle.у тебя от кода к коду что-то да не написано

Comment: в value, полный код показать возможности нет

Comment: код с map, в который добавляются значения и html с этим тегом

Comment: Я думаю знаю почему пусто.... Скорее всего тут дело в асинхронщине и ты работаешь с ajax запросами

Answer (score 0):

`Map` не преобразовывается в строку.

Можно сначала создать `Object` из `Map`.

```
JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(map));
```

```
var a = new Map();
a.set("key1","value1")
a.set("key2","value2")
a.set("key3","value3")

sessionStorage.setItem("saveData", JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(a)));
var result = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("saveData"));
```

Чтобы снова преобразовать распаршеный после JSON.parse() объект в `Map`

```
const a = new Map(Object.entries(result));
```

Comment: Попробовал, в итоге карта а пустая и при обращение к элементу ничего не вернулось